# How to create SharePoint web part from Class Library project?

Tags: sharepoint

I got a SharePoint web part proejct wth the output type set to Class Library to deploy on SharePoint farm.  It all bulds great no errors.

However, The project doesn't package as DWP because of the output type - In the Build menu VS2010 doesn't show Package item.

What is the way to create DWP package from this type of a project in Visual Studio 2010?

Should I create a new web part project from an empty SharePoint web part project and add the the cs files to complile and new project?  or there are some good ways?

Thanks,
Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a SharePoint Web Part project in Visual Studio and then add your class library project to it. There will be an option to package your web part project into a wsp file and deploy it. Make sure you add your class library to the GAC though in the web part project.